# Країна та держава: тотожні чи ні?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Як зрозуміти, коли доцільно застосувати слово "країна", а коли "держава"? Адже вони так часто зустрічаються у схожих контекстах.

В Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980) знайшла наступне тлумачення поняття "країна":

> [КРАЇ́НА](http://sum.in.ua/s/krajina), и, жін.
>   1. Територія, що становить єдність із погляду історії, природних умов, населення тощо.
>
> 2. **Те саме, що держава**. *Хто поверне в рабство ту країну, Де свободи стяг затрепетав?* (Максим Рильський, III, 1961, 81); *Наша країна
>      послідовно проводить політику мирного співіснування* (Радянська
>      Україна, 6.V 1959, 1); Соціалістичні країни;

Чи справді те саме?

> [ДЕРЖА́ВА](http://sum.in.ua/s/derzhava), и, жін. Апарат політичної влади в суспільстві.  //
>   Країна з таким апаратом політичної влади. *Будучи складовою і
>   невід'ємною частиною Радянського Союзу, Українська РСР виросла в одну
>   з найбільших держав Європи* (Наука і життя, 12, 1957, 1); Тринадцять
>   морів і два океани Омивають державу мою (Микола Нагнибіда, Пісня..,
>   1949, 64).

Поясню свої сумніви. На просторах інтернету є чимало джерел, які роз`яснюють різницю між цими поняттями, зокрема змістовний висновок міститься [тут](http://dovidka.biz.ua/riznitsya-mizh-derzhavoyu-i-krayinoyu/):

> В той час як «держава» — це в першу чергу політичне утворення, а
>   «країна» — культурне та соціально-економічне.

На сайті [ПОРАДИМО](http://poradumo.com.ua/243275-chim-vidrizniayetsia-krayina-vid-derjavi/) також акцентують різницю на тому, що:

> Країна – окрема географічна територія з населенням певної
>   національності та своєрідною культурою.
>
> Держава – автономна одиниця, існує на будь-якій території і володіє
>   суверенітетом і власною системою управління.

Але **це не словники і не енциклопедії**, тому виникають сумніви щодо того, **де вказана більш точна і правильна інформація**.

> *Чи тотожні за змістом поняття "країна" та "держава"?*

Comment: У [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0) держава є серед синонімів до слова "влада", хоча з ознакою "заст." І це, доречі, пояснює вираз "у аеропорту Президента зустрічали представники іноземних держав" - ніколи "країн", тому що це представники іноземної влади, а не країни.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коротко кажучи, слово «держава» може позначати дві речі:

1. Країна, яка має певні ознаки: сформований апарат влади, певний рівень суверенітету і т. ін. Не кожна країна є державою — є країни, що не мають державного суверенітету, історично були країни, що не мали чітко сформованого апарату влади і т. ін. Все ускладнюється тим, що немає ані точного переліку ознак, які має мати держава, ані узгодження щодо того, які народи/території без повних ознак державності можна було б називати хоча б країнами — але зазвичай поняття держави вужче за поняття країни.
2. Сам апарат влади такої країни (країни, що має ознаки державності, тобто держави у першому значенні).

Країна, як каже «Словник української мови» — це територія, що становить єдність із погляду історії, природних умов, населення тощо. Оскільки це поняття доволі розмите (хто зна: що вже країна, а що — ще край) і більшість таких об'єктів у сучасному світі мають ознаки державності, то це слово в  сучасному світі найчастіше використовують для держав. Однак загалом значення цього слова ширше: не лише не визнані світовою спільнотою держави можна називати країнами, а й доволі своєрідні регіони, що однак не претендують на державність.

Отже, якщо коротко: **на практиці «держава» й «країна» часто позначають майже те саме; але слово «держава» також може позначати не всю країну, а лише апарат влади, а не всю країну; а «країнами» можуть називати навіть території без чітких ознак державності**.

Є ще один погляд, що, однак, не заперечує вищенаведене, а навпаки, трішки пояснює його (зокрема те, чому слово «держава» має відразу два значення: країна з апаратом влади і сам апарат влади)… Коли ми кажемо «держава», ми акцентуємо увагу на апараті влади, системі керування, політичній системі; коли ми кажемо «країна», ми акцентуємо увагу на етнічному, культурному чи навіть особливостях природи. Зокрема, ми можемо сказати «спекотні/холодні країни», а от «спекотні держави» — вже щось не те.

<sub>Ця тема «країна vs. держава», по-моєму, пов'язана з використанням прийменників «на» і «в» стосовно України. Дехто вважає, що до України в сучасній мові можна використовувати лише «в», дехто (навіть серед українців, хоча серед українців такий погляд загалом рідкість) — що вимоги використання «в» необґрунтовані і чи то вони завжди взаємозамінні, чи то завжди треба «на». Я особисто вважаю, що вибір прийменника залежить від контексту: **про державу** (суверенну, що має апарат влади і чітко визначену територію) ми кажемо **лише «в»** («в Україні вшосте відбулися вибори президента»); але **можливе вживання «на»** («як у нас на Україні всі лани квітучі, так у нас на Україні люди всі співучі» (з пісні), «лише у нас на Україні росте калина при долині, вода джерельна з небом синім лише у нас на Україні, лише у нас на Україні всі люди щирі і гостинні» (з іншої пісні), «як умру, то поховайте мене на могилі серед степу широкого на Вкраїні милій» (Шевченко)), коли ми кажемо про Україну, як про якесь чітко не визначену єдність: можливо, в етнічному аспекті, можливо, в історичному (коли держави ще не було), можливо без чітко визначеної території (хто зна, що саме автори мали на увазі під «Україною», можливо, за межами рідної оселі — то для них вже «не Україна»; і навряд чи Бужинська мала на увазі, що рівно до кордону люди співучі, а там відразу — ні) — тобто **про країну** в широкому розумінні. Але це особисто мій погляд і я нікому його не нав'язую.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Якщо цей термін використовується в юридичному значенні, то краще застосовувати слово *держава*. Юристи використовують саме слово *держава*. Навіть є ціла дисципліна — [«Теорія держави і права»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Див., наприклад, [підручник «Загальна теорія держави і права» за ред. М. В. Цвіка й О. В. Петришина (Харків, «Право», 2009)](http://library.nlu.edu.ua/POLN_TEXT/KNIGI_2009/TEorijaDerjav_2009.pdf).

Comment: Можете наведете підтверженє тому. же юристи вживають саме держава і означенє?

Comment: "Теорія держави і права"?  https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: Дякуємо за виправлення/доповнення.